# A missing question in the list of recently deleted questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

I saw [a topology question](//math.stackexchange.com/q/2755499/290189) 15 minutes ago, and I had seen it somewhere else...  In fact, the question asker self-deleted [her own question](//math.stackexchange.com/q/2755288/290189) and re-posted it.

I would like to retrieve the URL of the self-deleted post from the [list of recently deleted posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last2days) in the 10k tools, but I *couldn't* find it.  The top item shown was deleted 7 hours ago.

[image: 10k tools]

*Is it impossible to retrieve the URL of a recently (self-)deleted post?  Is it a bug of the system?*

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Self-deleted questions are not shown in 10k tools. See: [Why are self-deleted posts not shown in the 10k Tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292531) and [Which deletions are not shown in 10k-tools? Are posts deleted by roomba shown there?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301539) on Meta Stack Exchange com. Somewhat related older post on this meta: [Is there need to patrol for deleted questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8540)

Comment: You're lucky (or good) to have 10k+ reputation. One day I will be able to see this page, just wait and you will see.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for comment and links.  It seems that SE wants to show a list of posts deleted by others instead of the self-deleted ones in the 10k tools.

Comment: @TrầnThúcMinhTrí I'm looking forward for this day.

Comment: I am not sure whether this helps too much if you want specifically self-deleted questions, In any case, I have posted this question, perhaps some useful replies appear there eventually: [Are there some tools to follow deletions on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28315)